# Two Buttons in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to get 2 buttons to work in rails for the same form. I have a login form with both an add user and signup button. I have 2 methods in my controller that already handle these 2 different requests.

However, I read the suggestions about using an additional parameter to parse to determine which button was called. For this solution wouldn't you need a level of indirection with another controller method to do the parsing? I read that having a controller call another controller isn't good MVC practice. In this case would calling another method within the MVC controller class be a bad practice?

My form:

```
<%= form_tag("users/delegate", :method=>"post") do %>
    <%= label_tag(:user, "Username:") %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:user) %>
    <br/><br/>
    <%= label_tag(:password, "Password:") %>
    <%= password_field_tag(:password) %>
    <br/><br/>
    <%= submit_tag "Login", :name=>'login' %>
    <%= submit_tag "Add User" %>
<% end %>
```

Also, how do I pass in the arguments from the post request into the other method? I 
essentially did but the arguments are not being passed. Do I need to pass in params to the other method? Is it a global variable?

```
def delegate
    if params[:login]
      login_post()
    else
      add_post()
    end
  end

def login_post
    user = params[:user]
    password = params[:password]
    errCode = UserModel.login(user,password)
    if (errCode>0)
        count = errCode
        errCode = 1
    end
    final_obj = {:errCode=> errCode, :count=>count}
    respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :json=>final_obj, :status=>200}
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this:

```
def delegate
  if params[:login]
    login_post(params[:user], params[:password])
  else
    add_post()
  end
end

def login_post(user, password)
  #do your things
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't you be passing in 2 values: params[:user] and params[:password]. How does Ruby know that the hash :password corresponds to params[:password] if the argument being passed in is a value?

Comment: `hash` password will be taken care by your implementation. It will be still `post`. Here you are just calling a method in your controller. That's it.

Comment: ohh I see how your update works. unfortunately, I also have a spec that says I can't change the method signature for login_post

Comment: Is there anyway to pass on the params hash without changing the method arguments? Similar to how it works in a post request to that controller method?